# Restore QList<bool> from QSettings

Tags: c++, qt

The save:

```
settings.setValue("profilesEnabled", QVariant::fromValue< QList<bool> >(profilesEnabled));
```

The restore:

```
profilesEnabled = settings.value("profilesEnabled").toList()); //error
```

But the toList() gives back a QList of QVariant, and the profilesEnabled is a QList of bool .

Is there any elegant way to convert it?
(i could iterate through the QList of QVariant and convert one by one)

Update:

```
QVariant var = QVariant::fromValue< QList< bool > >(profilesEnabled);
settings.setValue("profilesEnabled", var);
```

The second line crashes runtime:

```
QVariant::save: unable to save type 'QList<bool>' (type id: 1031).

ASSERT failure in QVariant::save: "Invalid type to save", file kernel\qvariant.cpp, line 1966
```

Comment: What is the format of `settings`? Can't save that to a file if you use `QSettings::IniFormat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach requires you to implement stream operators to make serialization of your custom `QVariant` type possible. I suggest to convert your data to `QVariantList` instead.

Saving:

```
QVariantList profilesEnabledVariant;
foreach(bool v, profilesEnabled) {
  profilesEnabledVariant << v;
}
settings.setValue("profilesEnabled", profilesEnabledVariant);
```

Loading:

```
profilesEnabled.clear();
foreach(QVariant v, settings.value("profilesEnabled").toList()) {
  profilesEnabled << v.toBool();
}
```